# Type application/netcdf is already registered as a variant of application/netcdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a standard rails app on rails 7 and I'm seeing this warning but not even sure where it comes from, any idea?

```
Type application/netcdf is already registered as a variant of application/netcdf.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is currently an [issue](https://github.com/mime-types/mime-types-data/pull/50) in the [`mime-types-data` gem](https://github.com/mime-types/mime-types-data) related to a duplicate definition of this mime type. If you look inside your `Gemfile.lock` file, you’ll probably find this gem used as a dependency. Luckily, this is just a warning without any consequences. Possible solutions are discussed in the issue.

Comment: To temporarily solve this for us, we pinned the version of that gem to 3.2021.1115 by adding this to our `Gemfile`: `gem "mime-types-data", "3.2021.1115" # TODO: See https://github.com/mime-types/mime-types-data/pull/50`. I also sub'd to that Issue so when it is resolved, we can just upgrade the gem and remove this entry from our `Gemfile`.

Comment: Yeah, we left the latest version but amended our rake tasks [monitoring script](https://habilis.net/cronic/) to ignore this particular warning in the error output so that it doesn’t trigger alerts. Whatever works is OK I guess... :)